# Error malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: c, sockets, openssl, malloc, httpresponse

I want to receive messages response from server so I wrote the function bellow:

```
char * receive_response(SSL *ssl, BIO *outbio) {
  int bytes;
  int received = 0;
  char *resp;
  resp = (char *) malloc(4096*sizeof(char));
  bytes = SSL_read(ssl, resp, 4096);
  resp[strlen(resp)] = '\0';
  if (bytes < 0) {
      BIO_printf(outbio, "\nError reading...\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  received += bytes;
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Received...%d bytes\n", received);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "%s", resp);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Receive DONE\n");
  return resp;
}
```

But I get the error: malloc():memory corruption when I run it.
The strange thing is it occurs when I call this function at the second times in main. It's ok at the first time. Please help me to understand it.

Comment: `memset(resp, 0, sizeof(resp));` is wrong... `sizeof(resp)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the block you allocated... though it might not matter.  Also, `strlen()` uses the null terminator to determine where the end of the string is, so you can't use it when the null hasn't been added yet.

Comment: Sorry, I use it when I declare resp as an array at first. I deleted it. And, the strlen(), thank you, my mistake. But the error still occurs.

Comment: Allocate an extra byte for the null terminator (4097 bytes, if you read up to 4096), and use `resp[bytes] = '\0';` instead of `resp[strlen(resp)] = '\0';` (after checking that `bytes` is >= 0).  Using `strlen()` to figure out where to put the null terminator like that is an error, because `strlen()` won't work properly if the null terminator isn't there yet.  Also, when do you free your buffer?

Comment: The problem with memory corruption errors is that you don't generally see them until the next time you try to allocate after you've messed things up.  Look at all the code that happens before the error for the problem.  Insert dummy allocations at strategic points to try and narrow it down if you need to.  Depending on your platform there's probably a way to validate the heap which can also be helpful in narrowing the problem down.  Valgrind may also be an option.

Comment: @Dmitri I changed it to resp[bytes] = '/0'. The value of bytes ( the number of byte actually read) is less than 4KB at the fist times I call function so I think I don't need to free the buffer. And all variable will be free when the function done, right?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I used some break point and find the error is caused the malloc function. And it only occurs at the second times I call receive_response() in main.

Comment: That's `'\0'`, not `'/0'`, right?  When the function exits, the local variables will be free, but the memory you allocated with `malloc()` will not be freed (unless you free it).

Comment: So how can I do that? I have to return the value.

Comment: You don't have to free it in this function... just free it later when you're done with it (you can do so through any pointer that points to the start of the block of memory, such as the one you assign your return value to).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try.

Comment: *... but I get the error: malloc():memory..."* - it sounds like the problem is elsewhere. Run it under Valgrind. Also see [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. Its a basic client that sends a request and reads a response.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not yet terminated with a `'\0'`, so you can't call `strlen` on it:

```
char * receive_response(SSL *ssl, BIO *outbio) {
  int bytes;
  int received = 0;
  char *resp;
  // add one extra room if 4096 bytes are effectivly got
  resp = malloc(4096+1);
  if (NULL == resp)
  { 
      perror("malloc");
      exit(1);
  }
  bytes = SSL_read(ssl, resp, 4096);
  if (bytes < 0) {
      BIO_printf(outbio, "\nError reading...\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  resp[bytes] = '\0';
  received += bytes;
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Received...%d bytes\n", received);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "%s", resp);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Receive DONE\n");
  return resp;
}
```

Another solution could be to called `calloc` instead of `malloc`...

Comment: He also needs to ensure that he doesn't read data into the last byte of the buffer, to make sure there's room for the '\0'.